# How to keep v-data-table header when sorting columns?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vtable

I am new to VueJS. I currently have trouble with my v-data-table. Every time I try to sort a table column, the header will be disappeared. After researching, I used '**fixed-header**' prop and set **the height** for the table. However, it didn't work. How can prevent the header disappear?

Here is my code

```js
   <VBTable
      top
      :auto-hide-footer="false"
      :server-paging="true"
      :loading="loading"
      :columns="headers"
      fixed-header
      :page.sync="internalPagination.page"
      :options.sync="internalPagination"
      :items="customers"
      :total="total"
      height="800"
      :show-select="false"
      :class="[{ 'empty-table': isEmpty, 'loading-table': loading }]"

    >
```

Comment: This is Vue 2, not Vue 3 as it says in the tags, right? Also, were does VBTable come from? Please create an example that reproduces the issue, or at least add enough code so that other can see what you are doing (data for header, items, etc.)